# Makefile loses configuration

Tags: makefile, valgrind, configure, autoconf

I'm pretty much a makefile novice so I don't even know the terminology I'm looking for. I'm trying to build the latest valgrind release alongside other 3rdparty tools my company uses. I basically have

```
../3rdparty/
           /Makefile <- What gets called to recursively build everything
           /valgrind/Makefile <- What I'm pasting below
           /valgrind/valgrind-3.16.1/Makefile <- what gets configure'd
```

So I can go into ../3rdparty/valgrind/valgrind-3.16.0/ and call...

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
make
```

...and have it succeed without issue. However, when I try to build it from the Makefile in ../3rdparty/valgrind I get errors due to configuration generated variables being lost. I can see it clean up everything, I can see configuration succeed, but when the make process starts I get warnings that aren't seen using the process above.

```
cc1: warning: switch -mcpu=cortex-a8 conflicts with -march=armv7ve switch
```

Which eventually leads to an error

```
<command-line>:0:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant pub_core_basics.h:78:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘ARM’
```

I basically copy pasted what is used for other 3rd party libs in our codebase and made changes where applicable....

```
include ../common.mak
VERSION=valgrind-3.16.1

all:  configure build #install

configure: configure_$(TARGET)
configure_$(TARGET):
        $(MAKE) distclean
        @echo -e "\nConfiguring $(VERSION) for $(TARGET)...\n"
        pushd $(VERSION)/ \
      && bash configure --host=${TARGET} \
      && popd
        touch $@
        @echo -e "\nConfiguration $(VERSION) complete for $(TARGET)...\n"

build: configure
        $(MAKE) "-SC" $(VERSION)

install: build
        $(MAKE) -SC $(VERSION) $@

# call folder's makefile targets verbatim
clean distclean:
        test -f $(VERSION)/Makefile && $(MAKE) -SC $(VERSION) $@ || :
        rm -f configure_*

uninstall:
        $(MAKE) -SC $(VERSION) $@
```

I'm guessing it's a one line thing, but I'd also be interested in any docs or websites that would be
useful. A lot of makefile tutorials go over the same super basic stuff.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "configuration generated variables being lost", or how you conclude that that is the nature of the issue.  It might be helpful if you presented the specific `make` command you are executing to produce the build failure you describe.

Comment: I'm just calling 'make', which kicks off the configuration. I see the correct results when it calls 'bash configure --host=${TARGET}', when it does the recursive make things start to screw up and I see warnings/errors. If I make the same configure & make call from the valgrind-3.16.1/ directory itself everything works. I don't know enough to be certain, but I'm guessing when calling './configure' in addition to setting up makefiles, maybe it sets up environmental variables? That's why it's feeling like some state is lost?

Comment: If you are just running `make`, then from where is the value for `TARGET` supposed to come?

Comment: In any case, the system information determined by `configure` is not held in environment variables after `configure` finishes.  That couldn't be done even if one wanted to do it. All persistent results of `configure` are written in *files*, especially Makerfiles.

Comment: Err ... Makefiles, not "Makerfiles".

Comment: However, Autotools `configure` scripts are sensitive to environment variables *provided to them*.  Running `./configure --help` in the Valgrind directory should provide (among other things) information about environment variables that influence its behavior.  I don't think there's anything wrong with the Makefile you present, but the way or context in which you are using it might be causing your problem.

Comment: So the TARGET is set by a call to 'source' that uses a .env file to set up the environment. This system is rather...convoluted. But, it's the same mechanism used to build all of these thirdparty libraries.

Comment: So I think I figured it out, in the valgring-3.16.1 directory, configure overrode the environment. Using my environment where I source the .env file, I'm introducing 'declare -x ARCH_ARM_DEFINES="-mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=hard -marm -march=armv7ve"' and so the -march=armv7ve conflicts with the -mcpu=cortex-a8 which is in all of the Makefile.in files. So I guess a8 is backwards compatible because I made sure to test the binaries created on our a7 controllers and there weren't any issues. I guess I need an old version of valgrind that was meant for a7.